# Unable to open file when run ionic project on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

My app published playstore now ı want to publish for apple store but When i build my app for ios (ionic capacitor run ios) ı get an error.

Error :

unable to open file(in target "app" in project "App")
Pods-app.debug.xcconfig

https://prnt.sc/163b0sb

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Please show the whole output from the console

Comment: https://prnt.sc/163b0sb  @AaronSaunders